# Swift increasing the width of tableview cell.textlabel

Tags: xcode, swift

I've tried adding a prototype cell and a label to it, among other approaches but can't seem to get there.

My table ends up displaying a couple of words followed by ... with most of the row empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Subclass UITableViewCell

Comment: Try setting the "Lines" property of your label to "0" in Interface Builder's "Attribute Inspector" tab, so it'll wrap the text of the label to the next line

Comment: @CjCoax, I tried this. However my goal is to have the text take up the width of the row before any wrapping. In my case the width of the row is enough. It won't seem to use much more than 1/3 of the available row width?